# calculate hours excluding weekends, holidays and non-working hours with SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

First of all I wanna say I am new to SSMS, so please bear with me if some things are not totally clear. So here is my issue.

I am trying to calculate time of 2 dates within the working hours and it should exclude the weekends and holidays.

I found a function script which calculated the time within the working hours and it did exclude the weekends. Now I just miss the part to exclude holidays. I have made a Holiday table which contains the name and date of the holidays.

I had found another function which calculates the time without the holidays, but I am getting way too much of output when I run a query with it. And I am not sure what is going wrong.

This is the new function I am using which is giving way too much output.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getWorkingHoursDiff(
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime)
RETURNS int AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @totaldays INT; 
    DECLARE @weekenddays INT;    

    DECLARE @ShiftStartOn datetime, @ShiftEndOn datetime
    Declare @startHourDiff int, @endHourDiff int

    set @ShiftStartOn = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@startDate,110)+' 08:00' as Datetime)
    set @ShiftEndOn = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @endDate,110)+' 18:00' as Datetime)

    declare @ShiftHours int
    set @ShiftHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @ShiftStartOn, @ShiftEndOn)

    set @startHourDiff = 0

    if @startDate between @ShiftStartOn and DATEADD(hour, @ShiftHours, @ShiftStartOn)
    begin
        set @startHourDiff = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @ShiftStartOn, @startDate)    
        set @startDate = @ShiftStartOn

        if(@startHourDiff < 0)    
        begin        
            set @startHourDiff = 0    
        end        
    end
    if DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) = 1 or DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) = 7
        set @startHourDiff = 0

    if exists(select 1 from table_holiday where DATEDIFF(day, start_time, @startDate) = 0)
        set @startHourDiff = 0    

    if @startDate > DATEADD(hour, @ShiftHours, @ShiftStartOn)
        set @startDate = DATEADD(day,1,@ShiftStartOn)    

    set @endHourDiff = 0    
    if @endDate between DATEADD(hour, -@ShiftHours, @ShiftEndOn) and @ShiftEndOn
    begin
        set @endHourDiff = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @endDate, @ShiftEndOn)            

        set @endDate = @ShiftEndOn

        if(@endHourDiff < 0)
            set @endHourDiff = 0    
    end
    if DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @endDate) = 1 or DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @endDate) = 7
        set @endHourDiff = 0

    if exists(select 1 from table_holiday where DATEDIFF(day, start_time, @endDate) = 0)
        set @endHourDiff = 0

    if @endDate < DATEADD(hour, -@ShiftHours, @ShiftEndOn)
        set @endDate = DATEADD(day,-1,@ShiftEndOn)

    SET @totaldays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) +1     

    SET @weekenddays = ((DATEDIFF(WEEK, @startDate, @endDate) * 2) + -- get the number of weekend days in between
                       CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + -- if selection was Sunday, won't add to weekends
                       CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @endDate) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  -- if selection was Saturday, won't add to weekends

    select @totaldays = @totaldays - @weekenddays

    declare @chkdtFromDate datetime, @chkdtToDate datetime

    select @chkdtFromDate =  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @startDate), 0)
    select @chkdtToDate =  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @endDate), 0)

    select @totaldays = @totaldays - COUNT(1) from table_holiday where (start_time between @chkdtFromDate and @chkdtToDate)

    return (@totaldays*@ShiftHours) - @startHourDiff - @endHourDiff
End
Go
```

This shows you the output with the both the functions I have added. The first function works perfectly fine as you see in the result. But it does not exclude holidays.

The second result you see gives even more hours as shown in column `OpenstaandeTijdInUren` while it should provide me a value of 10 hours since 05-30 is a holiday.

[image]

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). That function is already an unmanageable mess, IMHO, and it's not even complete yet.

Comment: And think about it: you're expecting SQL Server to know that May 30th is a holiday? How could SQL Server possibly know that? I don't even know what holiday that is. You need to tell SQL Server what days are holidays for your region, religion, company, etc.

Comment: I have made a table which have the data of the holidayname and date.

Comment: Holidays are not the only days when "work" does not occur. This is a difficult lesson to learn - disaster strikes without warning (and often without any preparation).

Answer (score 0):

to find weekdays, silly example below

```
declare @begin datetime2 = getdate() - .1
declare @end datetime2 = getdate() + .1
select 
    case when datepart(dw, @begin) in (2,3,4,5,6) and datepart(dw, @end) in (2,3,4,5,6) then rtrim(datediff(hour, @begin, @end)) + ' hours' else 'Weekend! Go Home!' end
```

Comment: Not bad but keep in mind that 7 does not always equal Sunday. This is controlled by setting DATEFIRST (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) . You need DATENAME to be sure you're include/excluding the correct days... Use: `DATENAME(DW,getdate()) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')`. Also note that you can determine DATEFIRST with @@DATEFIRST (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)