# SQL datetime calculation (working hours and weekend)

Tags: sql, datetime

I need help with a database and SQL. I have a table with requests containing their ID, requester ID, description, request submission time, and priority. Based on the priority, each request has a specific resolution time:

- priority 1 = 8 hours
- priority 2 = 16 hours
- priority 3 = 24 hours
- priority 4 = 32 hours

I want to create a new view that includes the ID, submission time, and the time by which the request must be resolved. I have to exclude weekends and holiday (will do it with simple table with datetime and Boolean column `isWorkingDay`) but I also have to exclude 17:00 - 08:00, because of business hours. So for example request with priority 1 created on Friday 16:00 must be resolved on Monday 15:00. Can you guys just point me in the right direction? Thank you very much.

Comment: Be aware that holidays differ based on local. So you might need to add a holiday table.

Comment: Each DBMS has its own, proprietary, built-in functions for doing date-time calculations. As far as I know there are no date-time functions in standard SQL. Hence I suggest that you [edit] your question and indicate which DBMS you are using. Refer to: [Why should I tag my RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) By the way - and not directly related to your question - I recommend that you take the [tour] and visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: @BartMcEndree I believe you mean [locale](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/locale) as in: _Be aware that holidays differ based on_ ___locale___

Comment: If your DBMS is SQL-Server then this might help us build some examples and collaborate on a solution: https://dbfiddle.uk/0h5LtgpE

Comment: May be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927404/calculate-hours-excluding-weekends-holidays-and-non-working-hours-with-ssms

Comment: @abra, ANSI/ISO SQL has had date-time calculation for 20 years or so. However, very few dbms's have implemented this.